# MS azure, zeppelin load scala file

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, blob, apache-zeppelin

I am following an OReilly book, "Advanced Analytics with spark" book. It seems that they expect you to use the command shell to follow the examples in the book (PuTTY). But i don't want to use that. I'd prefer to use Zeppelin. I'd like to create notebooks, but my own comments into the code etc.

So, using an Azure subscription, I spin up a Spark cluster and go into zeppelin. I am able to follow the guide fine for the most part. But there is one bit that trips me up. And its probably pretty basic.

You are asked to create a scala file called "StatsWithMissing.scala" with code in it. I do that. I upload it to blob to: //user/Zeppelin

(this is where i expect the Zeppelin user directory to be)

Then it asks you to run the following;
":load StatsWithMissing.scala"

At this point it gives the error:

:1: error: illegal start of definition

My first question is, where exactly is this scala file supposed to be on Blob Storage for Zeppelin to see it? How do i determine that? Is where i am putting it correct?
And second what does this message mean? Does it not like the Load statement?

I believe the Interpreter set at the top of the page is Livy, and that covers scala.

Any help would be great.

Regards

Conor

Comment: _And second what does this message mean? Does it not like the Load statement?_ - it means that you are trying to use Scala shell command (`:load`) in Zeppelin. It is not going to work. And if it was Scala shell it would require local path (could be handled with `SparkFiles` I guess).

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you expand on SparkFiles for me? I'm googling it, and getting swamped.

Comment: Or even, from within Zeppelin, how do i simply tell it, I have a Scala Class file sitting somewhere on azure, point to it, and let me use it. Can this be done?

Comment: You'll have to ask someone how spends more time with Zeppelin but I doubt it. And Spark files, would be useful for you, only with `spark-shell`. As far as I am aware, you should just create a jar for this.

Comment: ok, thanks User6910411.

Comment: I work with zeppelin to with spark but haven't load the class Simply you can copy the code from .scala file and paste in the zeppelin with out the outer class and main function. This should work